# Python: make a copy of object when equal old object to new

Tags: python, class, object

I've created new class based on default `str` class. I've also changed default methods like `__add__`, `__mul__`, `__repr__` etc. But I want to change default behaviour when user equal new variable to old one. Look what I have now:

```
a = stream('new stream')
b = a
b += ' was modified'
a == b
>>> True
print a
>>> stream('new stream was modified')
print b
>>> stream('new stream was modified')
```

So as you see each time I modify second variable Python also changes original variable. As I understand Python simply sends adress of variable `a` to variable `b`. Is it possible to make a copy of variable on creation like in usual `str`? As I think I need smth like **`new`** in C++.

```
a = 'new string'
b = a
b += ' was modified'
a == b
>>> False
```

**P.S.** Creation of the object begins in self.**new**() method. Creation is made like this:

```
def __new__(self, string):
  return(str.__new__(self, string))
```

It is more complicated, because it takes care of unicode and QString type, first getting str object from them, but I think it's not neccessary.

Comment: I think that the problem is really in how you've implemented `__add__`.

Comment: `b = a` just assigns another identifier, "b", to the same object which identifier "a" currently references.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can change the behavior of the assignment operator, but there are explicit ways to create a copy of an object rather than just using a reference.  For a complex object, take a look at the [copy module](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html).  For a basic sequence type (like `str`), the following works assuming you're implementing slice properly:

### Code

```
a = str('abc')

#A slice creates a copy of a sequence object. 
#[:] creates a copy of the entire thing.
b = a[:]

#Since b is a full copy of a, this will not modify a
b += ' was modified'

#Check the various values
print('a == b' + str(a == b))
print(a)
print(b)
```

### Output

```
False
abc
abc was modified
```